# my QT fails to config a project because of the "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH"

Tags: qt

I downloaded the source code from git:https://github.com/MITK/MITK, but when I tried to config the code in QT, it always shows the following issues:

/Users/cjz/CCode/MITK/CMakeLists.txt:211: error: By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested version 5.6.0) with any of the following names: Qt5Config.cmake qt5-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

I checked on the Internet and was told that I should set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=qtbase

since my qt was installed at "/Users/cjz/Qt5.9.2", I set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/cjz/Qt5.9.2

but the problem remains the same.

I also tried cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/cjz/Qt5.9/
but it did not work either.

I totoally have no idea how to adress this problem, anyone helps me? thank you.

Comment: What is your OS? is it Linux

Comment: it's MAC 10.12.6

Comment: Try from scratch, stick to below "general Installation guide", try to spot at which step it fails ...

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you ever get to the bottom of this? The MITK build instructions and cmake files for Linux/Mac are bad right now, it won't build out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Qt documentation for installing from sources? here : [General Installation Information](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html)

For Linux, Follow this guide:
[Qt for Linux/X11 - Building from Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html)